# How do I add a class to a CSS element in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I want to add a hover class using the Cypress testing framework. What commands or assertions should I use?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense - why would Cypress be responsible for updating the DOM? It's for testing that whatever you're using to update the DOM does so correctly.

Comment: I want Cypress to check whether a transition occurs after the user hovers, and adding a CSS class was cited as a workaround for their lack of a hover command

Comment: Cited where? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover#Trigger), [recipe](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__chrome-remote-debugging). The principle is similar to clicking `:hov` then forcing element state in chrome devtools Elements/Styles.

Comment: Use `.invoke('addClass', 'some_class_name_here');`. You can read more about this in [Cypress documentation here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you add

```
.invoke('addClass', 'overDue')
```

To your cypress test in order to add a class

Answer (score 0):

Testing css pseudo-classes like :hover can be tricky with Cypress and I'm not sure modifying classes is a good way to go.
However, this can certainly be achieved with Puppeteer's page.hover() method.

You could create a cypress task under your plugins/index.js that launches Puppeteer (in case you want to control the tests from within Cypress), and return whatever values you need to confirm that your application behaves in an expected way.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//...

on('task', {
        async launchPuppeteer(param1, param2){
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            //do something

            await page.hover(someElementThatReactsToHover)

            //do other stuff

      return valuesForCypress
      }
})
```

And then in your .spec file you could call this task as follows:

```
cy.task('launchPuppeteer', {param1: 'whatever1', param2: 'whatever2'})
            .then(valuesForCypress => cy.wrap(valuesForCypress).should('eq', expectedValues))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small simple "hackaround" the lack of hover support in cypress. I use focus() along with :focus, :hover { // ... } in my css. For the projects I work on, we usually match the focus style to hover, so if you do, then you can use this hack.

Assuming your CSS has this type of structure:

```
<style>
  a {
    color: red;
  }
  a:hover,
  a:focus {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

You can use cy.get($elm).focus() then test the attributes. Below is a full example from a working test.

```
cy.get('a.navigation__link')
    .not('a.navigation__link--active')
    .each($el => {
        cy.wrap($el).should('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')
        cy.wrap($el).focus().should('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(211, 50, 57)')
    })
```

Not trying to lead anyone down the wrong road here, this is just a workaround that can help you achieve the same visual result as hover, however its not an exact hover test.